# Getting a value of a sibling field in a field resolver

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

Say, I have these typeDefs (just an example):

```
type CityInfo {
  CityState: {
    City: String!
    State: String!    
  }

  Zip: String!
}

type Query {
  CitiesStatesZips: [CityInfo]
}
```

Now, say there is a rest api that gives me a list of Zip codes and there is another REST API that returns City/State by Zip code. I can write this resolver:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    CitiesStatesZips: (parent, args, {dataSources}) => dataSources.ZipApi.getZipCodes()
  },
  CityInfo: {
    CityState: (parent, args, { dataSources }) => dataSources.CityStateApi(** HOW DO I PASS ZIP HERE **) 
  }
}
```

In `CityState` field resolver I need to pass the value of `Zip` field of the same object - how do I access it?

Comment: `resolvers.CityInfo.Zip`?

Comment: just ``parent.zip` (fields usually lowercased)  ... assuming `CitiesStatesZips` returns an array of objects with zip field (solved sooner for sure)

Comment: @xadm - that worked, thank you. You can add this as an answer and I will mark it as such

Answer (score 2):

If `CitiesStatesZips` returns an array of objects (`CityInfo` type)  with `zip` field ...

... then `zip` is already resolved when `CityState` resolver is called ... then you can simply use `parent.zip` as an arg for datasource call.